# why the window is cutting my table when i am doing a subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, subplot

Hi my goal its to have a graph and at the left side have a small table with some parameters about that graph.

My code is this:

```
# Fazer o grafico
    table_data= [ ['δ', str(round(self.novodelta,3))],
    ['k', str(round(k,3))],
    ['h', str(round(h,3))],   ]

    plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    plt.plot(self.Observacoes,T, '-o')
    plt.plot(self.Observacoes,C, '-o')
    plt.plot(self.Observacoes,Lim_inf_CUSUM)
    plt.plot(self.Observacoes,Lim_sup_CUSUM)
    the_table = plt.table(cellText=table_data,
                  loc="left")
    plt.title("CUSUM")
    plt.xlabel("Amostras")
    plt.legend(["T", "C", "Limite inferiror", "Limite Superior"],loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.12),fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=4)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(min(self.Observacoes), max(self.Observacoes)+1, 1.0))
    plt.tight_layout()


    observacoes=self.Observacoes
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
    plt.plot(observacoes,E, '-o')
    plt.plot(observacoes,LC_EWMA)
    plt.plot(observacoes,LSC_EWMA)
    plt.plot(observacoes,LIC_EWMA)
    plt.title("EWMA")
    plt.xlabel("Amostras")
    plt.legend(["E", "LC", "Limite inferiror", "Limite Superior"],loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.15),fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=4)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(min(self.Observacoes), max(self.Observacoes)+1, 1.0))
    plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Output of my code]

How you can see the table is on top of the y axis and the window is cutting the first column, i would like to fix this, i mean this should have some space before the table and after the table the second graph will have another table but i'm trying to do this one first

EDIT

I forgot to mention that i m using pyqt5 to build this and this append when i press one button to pop up the graphs

EDIT 2

here its a minimal, reproducible example

```
import os
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import statistics
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton



ui_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(ui_path, "problem.ui"))

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 button - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)

        button.clicked.connect(self.graph)

    def graph(self):
        self.values=[2,4,5,6]

        table_data= [ ['δ', 1],
    ['k', 2],
    ['h', 3],   ]

        plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
        plt.plot(self.values,"-o")
        the_table = plt.table(cellText=table_data,
                  loc="left")
        plt.title("CUSUM")
        plt.xlabel("samples")
        plt.show()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app =  QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here you can see same problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeRdp.png)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: was that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but i don't know if is the best one.

In the code of the minimal, reproducible example

I create a subplot with one line and two columns
My idea was to plot the first column the table and in the second one the graph

```
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.plot(self.values,"-o")
    plt.title("CUSUM")
    plt.xlabel("samples")
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    the_table = plt.table(cellText=table_data,
                  loc="center") # tu put in the center 
    plt.axis('off') # turn off the axis and the outside box
    plt.show()
```

The output was:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4LwY.png)